# Intel XDK social login

Tags: javascript, html, oauth-2.0, social-networking, hybrid-mobile-app

i want to implement social network login in my intel xdk app. Have any good plugins for implement this? [for facebook login, g+ login, twitter login]./ how to implement social network login in intel xdk app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel XDK application is nothing else but JavaScript application.

Below are links to JavaScript login tutorials from Facebook and Google:

[Facebook login flow for web](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)

[Google web sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

By plugins you probably means Cordova(Phonegap) plugins. 
Cordova plugins are used to add native functionality to JavaScript apps. 
Albeit, we don't need them in order to implement login with Facebook/Google such plugins exist:

[Cordova Facebook plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

[Cordova Google plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus)

These plugins allow to connect Cordova app to native Facebook/Google apps and make some interesting things, not only login.